# Method in Kotlin should return a boolean

Tags: kotlin

I want to display home screen when I press the navigation item which I called "Home". I can't do that because the method should return a type which is a boolean.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home ->
 // I want to display the home screen here
        else ->
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, the `when` `statement` will return the value from the selected statement.

```
   return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home ->
            // your code
            return true
        else ->
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Comment: Great @Ali_ahmed.  Please accept answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can, just place this line `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` after `when` block:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home ->
            // your code here
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Make sure that you include all menu items in the `when` block.  
This way you have a `Boolean` returned from the method.  
In your question you mentioned navigation item, so if you're talking about Navigation Drawer the you should implement `onNavigationItemSelected()` and not `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.miNavUsePassword ->
            // your code here
    }

    return true
}
```